# How can fetch tumbler images from tumbler in specific order like by date or random through tumbler api

Tags: ios, api, url, tumblr, webrequest

I am facing the problem to fetch the data from tumbler in specific order . I am trying to fetch  data in sorted order from tumbler through tumbler api which is as follows :

url :  "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=illustration&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

but I am unable to find out specific url through which i can send the order value (sorted key) with url for fetching the sorted order data

So please help me how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is support for ordering directly through the Tumblr API. You will have to get the unsorted JSON response and sort manually in your app for any of the supported [response fields](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#common-fields)